# QWidget background color does not fully cover the QWidget

Tags: c++, qt4, qwidget, qtstylesheets

Using Qt Creator, I have set a QWidget's background property to black. However, some parts of the QWidget, more specifically, between QFrames/QGroupBoxes are still in its system's default color.

Now, I thought that the QFrames and QGroupBoxes need to have its background property set to black too, but it did not work. I have also tried setting the border-color to black, but it does not work, since by default borders, margins are set to 0.

```
QWidget { background: black; }
```

Any advice on this issue?

**EDIT**

The QWidgets are placed in QMdiArea. However, if I make it a QWindow, it works. However, I want the QWidgets to be in the QMdiArea. Also, if I just show the QWidgets as it is, the spaces that I have mentioned above are transparent.

Comment: Can you clarify how you are setting the background to black?

Comment: As I said, I used stylesheet by setting the background property to black. I have added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution. It seems that you need to set the background color at the QMdiSubWindow, not at QWidget. Don't know why, but it seems logical.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some widgets within another widget, and are setting the contained widgets to be black, but then the space between them is not black.  If that is the case, it is likely because you have a layout in the containing widget, which allocates space between each contained widget.  The empty space between widgets will be drawn with the containing widget's background color.

Comment: I have set every container's background property to black. The spaces between the containers still remains system color though.

Comment: @Skaty: After the edit to the question, I'm out of my experience range.  I've never used the mdi area.